# start the stopped AWS instances using ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to `stop/start` the particular `group` of instances listed in the `hosts` file under group `[target]`.
following playbook works fine to stop the instances.

```
---
- hosts: target
  remote_user: ubuntu

  tasks:
  - name: Gather facts
    action: ec2_facts

  - name: Stop Instances
    local_action:
        module: ec2
        region: "{{region}}"
        instance_ids: "{{ansible_ec2_instance_id}}"
        state: stopped
```

But when I am trying to start these instances, it's not working as the `ec2_facts` is not able to `ssh` into the instances (since they are stopped now) and get the `instance-ids`

```
---
- hosts: target
  remote_user: ubuntu

  tasks:
  - name: start instances
    local_action:
        module: ec2
        region: "{{region}}"
        instance_ids: "{{ansible_ec2_instance_id}}"
        state: running
```

I have already seen the documentation which make use of `dynamic inventory` file for hosts and the way of hard-coding the `instance-ids`. I want to start the instances whose `IPs` are listed in the `target` group of `hosts` file.

Comment: what do you mean by it is not working What is the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution, Following is the `ansible-task` that worked for me.

```
---
- name: Start instances
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    instance_ids:
      - 'i-XXXXXXXX'
    region: ap-southeast-1
  tasks:
    - name: Start the feature instances
      ec2:
        instance_ids: '{{ instance_ids }}'
        region: '{{ region }}'
        state: running
        wait: True
```

[Here is the Blog post on How to start/stop ec2 instances with ansible](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/02/ansible-playbook-to-start-or-stop-aws.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

**Option 1**

Use AWS CLI to query the instance-id of a stopped instance using its IP or name. For example, to query the instance id for a given instance name:

```
shell: aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values={{inst_name}}' --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId'
register: inst_id
```

**Option 2**

Upgrade Ansible to version 2.0 (Over the Hills and Far Away) and use the new ec2_remote_facts module

```
- ec2_remote_facts:
    filters:
      instance-state-name: stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add [gather_facts: False](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#turning-off-facts) to prevent Ansible from trying to SSH into the hosts since they're not running:

```
- hosts: target
  remote_user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: false
```

If you need to gather facts after the instances have started up then you can use the [setup](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html) module to explicitly gather facts after they have booted up.

Edit: I just realized that the issue is that you're trying to access the ansible_ec2_instance_id fact that you can't get because the instance is down.  You might want to take a look at [this custom module called ec2_lookup](https://github.com/edx/configuration/blob/master/playbooks/library/ec2_lookup) that will let you search fetch AWS instance IDs even when the instances are down. Using this you can get a list of the instances you're interested in and then start them up.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. But this is a custom module, how to exactly use it.

Comment: The [best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html) document describes the directory structure Ansible uses.  If you create a directory called `library` and put custom modules there then you can use them just like any other module.

Comment: Any other way that ansible itself support?

Comment: @AjeetKhan I start my instances using ansible. Can you tell me what error message you get.

Comment: @helloV In my script I am trying to get `instance_ids` through `gather_facts `but since the instances are stopped the `gather_facts` can't ssh into the instances to get the `instance_ids`

Comment: @AjeetKhan i am sure you would have figured out the way but just for documentation - you could have used hosts: localhost and ssh to ur localhost . ec2_remote_facts would have still worked to give you the instanceids